# Import error in bson and pymongo in python3.6 version

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, bson

I had python3.5 minimal in my Ubuntu 16.04. I upgraded it to python3.6 using the following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3.6
```

Now, when i try to import bson or pymongo in python3.6.12 env, i get `"No module name bson/pymongo".`
But when i try to import bson or pymongo in python2.7, it gets imported without any error.
What am i missing?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Python 2 and Python 3 install packages in different places. Any packages you installed for Python 2 will not be visible or usable from Python 3.

To use them from Python 3, install them again using Python 3.